# Display each group of a data.frame in a separate table in shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to split a dataframe based on a grouping variable and then display each group as a table in a separate box in a shiny dashboard app.
However, I keep getting the same group in all the tables. The title for each box is shown correctly though and if I introduce some print statements I can also see that the correct data seems to be handled.
Below is an example that reproduces the problem:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(uiOutput("tables"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$tables <- renderUI({
        df <- iris %>%
            group_by(Species) %>%
            group_split()
        
        ui <- tagList()
        for(df.split in df) {
            id <- paste0("tbl_", df.split[1, "Species"])
            output[[id]] <- renderTable(head(df.split, 3))
            ui <- append(
                ui,
                box(
                    title = df.split[1, "Species"],
                    tableOutput(id)
                )
            )
        } 
        return(ui)
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is an interesting case. I think this should work, tell me if it is not :

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

multiple_dt <- function(output,id,table_list){
  ns <- NS(id)
  ui <- tagList(lapply(table_list,function(df.split){
    box(
      title = as.character(df.split[1, "Species"]),
      tableOutput(ns(as.character(df.split[1,"Species"]))),
      output[[ns(df.split[1,"Species"])]] <- renderTable(head(df.split, 3))
    )
  }))
  ui
}

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(uiOutput("tables"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$tables <- renderUI({
    df <- iris %>%
      group_by(Species) %>%
      group_split()
    
    multiple_dt(output,"tables",df) 
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I think there are multiple errors in your code. First of all, I think that your appending is not working correctly because the tables to be rendered are not well stored in the list (they are just successively stored while there should be a hierarchical dimension, which is made in the function `multiple_dt` with the `lapply`).
Moreover, when you create complicated shiny objects like this one, you should create a new function to render it, like I did with a structured code having an NS id, etc.

Comment: Interesting approach! What would you say is the advantage of using a separate namespace for the function? I only know using namespaces from when you create a module (what I think would be an alternative approach that works here too).

Comment: I would say that using ns here is a way to normalize the id's labels : with its usage, you can't create incoherent ids so it is easy to retrieve them.
I agree that the module approach works here too. I think that this solution is just a "hand made" module.

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you! One additional comment. Using df.split[1, "Species"] returns a 1x1 tibble, which the ns() function doesn't seem to mind, but without it you have to convert it to a single value first.

Comment: Oh, and 
"multiple_dt <- function(id,table_list){" should be 
"multiple_dt <- function(output, id,table_list){"